# Data-collection in Excel-VBA using nested dictionaries

Tags: vba, excel

**Introduction**

I have a spreadsheet in Excel, looking like this:
[image]
I collect and sort the values in the column labelled "Antal dagar venting", based on the values in the columns "Nivå 1" and "Nivå 2".

**My current code for collecting this data is:**

In a class-module:

```
Option Explicit

Private pAntalDagar As Long
Private pDelårsaker As Dictionary

' Tid
Public Property Get AntalDagar() As Long
    AntalDagar = pAntalDagar
End Property
Public Property Let AntalDagar(Value As Long)
    pAntalDagar = Value
End Property

' Delårsaker
Public Property Get Delårsaker() As Dictionary
    Set Delårsaker = pDelårsaker
End Property
Public Property Set Delårsaker(Value As Dictionary)
    Set pDelårsaker = Value
End Property
```

In a regular module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub samle_data(fra As Date, til As Date)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim tid As Long
    Dim hovudårsak As String, delårsak As String, feil_melding As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim hovudårsaker As clsHovudårsak
    Dim dictHovudårsaker As Dictionary, dictDelårsaker As Dictionary, dictManglandeVerdier As Dictionary

    Set hovudårsaker = New clsHovudårsak
    Set dictHovudårsaker = New Dictionary: Set dictManglandeVerdier = New Dictionary

    For Each c In Range(Registrering.Range("A3"), Registrering.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp))
        If IsNumeric(c.Offset(0, 6).Value2) Then
            tid = CLng(c.Offset(0, 6).Value2)
        Else
            tid = 0
        End If
        If tid < 0 Then
            feil_melding = "Ventetida er mindre enn null dagar"
            dictManglandeVerdier.Add Item:=feil_melding, Key:=c.Offset(0, 6).AddressLocal
        ElseIf Len(c.Offset(0, 1).Value2) = 0 Then
            feil_melding = "Det manglar hovudårsak"
            dictManglandeVerdier.Add Item:=feil_melding, Key:=c.Offset(0, 6).AddressLocal
        ElseIf Len(c.Offset(0, 2).Value2) = 0 Then
            feil_melding = "Det manglar delårsak"
            dictManglandeVerdier.Add Item:=feil_melding, Key:=c.Offset(0, 6).AddressLocal
        ElseIf Len(c.Offset(0, 5).Value2) <> 0 Then
            hovudårsak = CStr(c.Offset(0, 1).Value2)
            delårsak = CStr(c.Offset(0, 2).Value2)
            If dictHovudårsaker.Exists(hovudårsak) Then
                Set hovudårsaker = dictHovudårsaker(hovudårsak)
                hovudårsaker.AntalDagar = hovudårsaker.AntalDagar + tid
                Set dictDelårsaker = hovudårsaker.Delårsaker
                If dictDelårsaker.Exists(delårsak) Then
                    dictDelårsaker(delårsak) = dictDelårsaker(delårsak) + tid
                Else
                    dictDelårsaker.Add Item:=tid, Key:=delårsak
                    hovudårsaker.AntalDagar = tid
                    Set hovudårsaker.Delårsaker = dictDelårsaker
                End If
            Else
                Set hovudårsaker = New clsHovudårsak
                Set dictDelårsaker = New Dictionary
                hovudårsaker.AntalDagar = tid
                Set hovudårsaker.Delårsaker = dictDelårsaker
                dictDelårsaker.Add Key:=delårsak, Item:=tid
                dictHovudårsaker.Add Key:=hovudårsak, Item:=hovudårsaker
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    For Each v In dictManglandeVerdier
        feil_melding = CStr(dictManglandeVerdier(v)) & " i celle " & CStr(v) & " i registreringsarket." & vbCrLf _
                                    & vbCrLf & "Data frå denne linja vil ikkje verte teke med i grafane."
        MsgBox Prompt:=feil_melding, Buttons:=vbExclamation, Title:="Mangler data"
    Next v

    Call skriv_data(dictHovudårsaker)
End Sub

Sub skriv_data(dictHovudårsaker As Dictionary)
    Dim hovudårsak As Variant, delårsak As Variant
    Dim hovudårsaker As clsHovudårsak
    Dim dictDelårsaker As Dictionary

    For Each hovudårsak In dictHovudårsaker
        Set hovudårsaker = dictHovudårsaker(hovudårsak)
        Set dictDelårsaker = hovudårsaker.Delårsaker
        'Debug.Print "Hovudårsak: " & hovudårsak & " - Tid: " & hovudårsaker.AntalDagar
        For Each delårsak In dictDelårsaker
            'Debug.Print "Delårsak: " & delårsak & " - Tid: " & dictDelårsaker(delårsak)
        Next delårsak
    Next hovudårsak
End Sub

Sub test()
    Call samle_data(#1/1/2010#, #12/31/2015#)
End Sub
```

**The problem**

I think the loop described in the procedure `skriv_data` shows the output I want pretty well. The output for the sample workbook I posted at the top would be something like this:

[image]

Now, I believe the code works as it should, or at least I haven't found any bugs in it yet. However I feel it is rather convoluted, so I was wondering if someone here has any suggestions for how I can improve it? I'd like to avoid using Pivot-tables.

Answer (score 1):

`Len(rng.Value2) = 0` is not as efficient as `IsEmpty(rng)`. Not sure if that function is the same in every language. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360651/excel-how-to-check-if-a-cell-is-empty-with-vba

I don't think any of your `CStr` are necessary.

It is confusing to have variables with similar names -- `hovudårsak` and `hovudårsaker` for instance.

Why did you make it a class module with properties? It doesn't seem to benefit at all by that design choice over a `Type`.

Comment: Using `Len` instead of `IsEmpty` catches different stuff, as (partly) pointed out in [the question](http://ow.ly/SSjoX) the one you linked to is marked as a duplicate of. The difference in performance seems to be negligible too, according to [my simple test](http://ow.ly/SSjsM). Totally agree on the naming of variables, gonna look into that. The reason for making a `class` instead of a `type` is because I may be doing some handling of the values stored in it later on, although I for now have focused on just collecting the data. Could you expand on why a `type` would be better?

Comment: Not better per se, but shorter code. Your reason is good enough to keep it a `Class`. I'll see what else I can observe in your code.

Comment: Thanks - I'd be especially interested if you can see any better way to structure the dictionaries and / or types / classes to make the code easier to read.